# Python - Count most frequent elements in list of same length

Tags: python, string, frequency

I've been looking for answers to this for the last few hours, without finding the answer I was looking for, so I decided to ask here instead.

So, say I've got a list of data with the same length such as;

```
0004000000350
0000090033313
0004000604363
040006203330b
0004000300a3a
0004000403833
00000300333a9
0004000003a30
```

What would be the most efficient way to match the most occurring characters in each position.

An example output would be something like;

```
0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3
```

Edit: Thanks for the answers, gave me just what I was looking for! :)

Edit 2: Thought I'd add to the question as it may be the easiest way to figure it out.  With the suggested answers, how would you go about adding a total count, as well as having some sort of percentage?  Since it's a large set of data, the most common occurrences alone isn't as clear as I was hoping it would of been.

Comment: Why is the fourth element of the expected output is 4 and not 0?

Comment: In the example set of data, the most frequent character in position 4, is 4. 4 having 5 occurrences verses 0 having 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zip the list of strings to "transpose" them to present columns in the same iterator, apply `collections.Counter` on them, and use `most_common` method, remove the unwanted data

```
data="""0004000000350
0000090033313
0004000604363
040006203330b
0004000300a3a
0004000403833
00000300333a9
0004000003a30"""

import collections

counts = [collections.Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0] for x in zip(*data.splitlines())]
```

this yields:

```
['0', '0', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '3', '3', '3']
```

(join the characters to recreate a string if needed using `"".join(counts)`)

Answer (score 2):

You start using `zip` in order to interleave the characters in each string that are in the same relative position. Then take the mode of each tuple using [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) , and join the resulting strings from the generator expression:

```
l = ['0004000000350', '0000090033313', '0004000604363', '040006203330b', 
     '0004000300a3a', '0004000403833', '00000300333a9', '0004000003a30']

from scipy.stats import mode
''.join(mode(i).mode[0] for i in list(zip(*l)))
```

**Output**

```
'0004000003333'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
''.join(Counter(i).most_common(1)[0][0] for i in zip(*l))
```

Where `l` is your list of strings.

Comment: `expected str instance, tuple found` Missing `[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Without import I would do :

```
data = [
"0004000000350",
"0000090033313",
"0004000604363",
"040006203330b",
"0004000300a3a",
"0004000403833",
"00000300333a9",
"0004000003a30",
]

# return the most common elemebt in an iterable
most_common = lambda ite: max(ite, key=ite.count)  

# print the most_common in each columns
print(map(most_common, zip(*data)))

# ['0', '0', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '3', '3', '3']
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that `max`  with that `key` is O(n²), though.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has used pandas, so by  using `pandas` you can achieve this easily and efficient

```
a = """0004000000350
0000090033313
0004000604363
040006203330b
0004000300a3a
0004000403833
00000300333a9
0004000003a30"""

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([list(j) for j in a.strip().split('\n')])
result =  df.mode().to_string(header=None,index=None)
print(result)

""" output 
 0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  3  3  3  3
"""
```